# Gimp - single operation to crop and resize to fit to specific size

Tags: gimp

This solution is already done in **Photoshop**:

1. I set result image specific size.
2. Select crop area (in this case crop area rectangle have a proportional resizing ratio to result image size).
3. Make crop and get result image with specific size.

This is useful to create, for example, thumbnails with manual selected area by single operation.

Now i try do same in **Gimp**. Is that possible with single operation?

Answer (score 4):

*Crop* and *scale* are very different things, it appears unlikely to get them both in one single operation.

Nevertheless it is not needed to use a calculator for getting a desired aspect ratio of a (crop) selection in Gimp. We can define this ratio on making our crop or crop selection by just using any values we like. If for example the desired image format should be 200 x 170 pixels wide, just type in these values in the corresponding box:

[image]

We can now drag or move this box in any direction or change its size but the ratio will remain 200:170. Before exporting we just scale the image to the desired 200 x 170 pixels:

[image]

If we want to crop the image to exact 200 x 170 without scaling later we need to tell it in the dropdown menu next to the input box to not only use a fixed ration but also a fixed size.

Comment: This is annoying and error prone. When exporting images for the web, Photoshop allows crop to also resize to the target size, intuitively - just set to "fixed size" and specify the size, the difference being you are allowed to drag the crop box to any size (but it maintains the ratio). When you press ENTER, the crop and scale is done at once.

In GIMP you need to crop to the ratio, then go into the Scale image and scale down to the target size. If you forget this step, you may upload a huge image to your web page.

Comment: what is the name of the panel on the left in the screen shot? how do you open that?

Answer (score 2):

Not without a script. But you can force the crop to have the proper aspect ratio.

Comment: Yes, i can use proper aspect ratio.. But in this case i must use more than 2 operation for this solution: need using calculator to calculate ratio, crop with ratio and resizing.